Configure Wildfly micrometer to set name of application
We are using Wildfly 33 (jboss 7.1.0) and we have configured it to use micrometer. It now sends the metrics via an Open Telemetry collector to a prometheus instance. This works great but the problem we face is that all metrics are tagged with app=wildfly and job=wildfly
datasources_jdbc_prepared_statement_cache_access_count{app="wildfly",deployment="",job="wildfly",name="****",subdeployment="",type="data-source"}
undertow_request_count_total{app="****.ear",deployment="****.ear",job="wildfly",name="ApplicationConfig",subdeployment="****.war",type="servlet"}

Does someone knew how we could change the name of the tag: app or/and job
For example setting the tag
app="wildfly_app_1", job="wildfly_job_1"


I found an answer from this: https://groups.google.com/g/wildfly/c/lLdwNV6EaAo where you can change job by setting the environment variable: OTEL_SERVICE_NAME but

I got this to work be reading the answer provided from a google group (here) To change the name of job you must set the OTEL_SERVICE_NAME environment variable.
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=wildfly_job_1

That become the job=wildfly_job_1 and after it pathed through open telemetry it was exposed as the tag: exported_job=wildfly_job_1.
